# How to stop bots and spams from submitting comments?

Tags: php, javascript, bots

Currently

1. I am using captcha image
2. I created text field and hide it using javascript. i want its value to be empty on server side, because bots are supposed to fill all the fields on the form. if value isn't empty it it does not process comment.
3. I also use timestamps to check how long it took while submitting the comment. I supposed if the comment was submitted within 15 seconds, it comes from bot so i also stop processing the comment.

But still I couldn't control bots to submit my comments form.
Please help what should I do now?

Comment: add a hidden field called something obvious like 'username' and if its filled in it would show that its a bot.

Comment: They might not be bots but human spammers.

Comment: How to prevent from human spammers Waleed Khan?

Comment: Do people have to register on your site? Cause if they do, you can make sure you accept people, or build an extra system in, like people have to click on a link that people have to click in their mail. I have a system people have to register, and only the admins can accept people in. This way I know who I accept and who allow to post. I can understand this is hard if its a site where you dont have to register, which makes it way harder.

Answer (score 4):

Add a hidden field with a misleading id / name

`<input type="hidden" id="Username" name="Username" value=""/>`

If a bot comes along and fills out your form, they are likely to fill in the hidden field, which users should not be able to, so just disallow the submission if the hidden field has data.

Answer (score 1):

Why not implement [Akismet](http://akismet.com/) and let them handle it for you? They have a well documented API, and thousands of people rely on it for spam prevention on Wordpress blogs. I haven't seen a spam comment in probably 3 years now using Akismet on my wife's blog.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use **no-follow** for all links in comments. This will not prevent the spam, but it will remove much of the incentive for spamming. ( [see here how it works](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nofollow) )
2. Require **user authentication** to be able to comment.
3. Use non-descriptive form elements ( don't name
   the div "comment").

Answer (score 0):

Lyuben Todorov has suggested a good solution to prevent BOT spammers. But if you still have spam and probably its human spam, then use [Akismet](http://akismet.com) anti spam system.

Answer (score -1):

Try to create unique captcha to stop any standard bots (but if someone wants to get exactly you spammed it wouldn't work).

Another approach is to add verification by phone number.

Comment: i'm talking about unique protection. it can be something like 'Please,  select our site name from given images' or whatever.