# PHP MySQLi prepared statement for SELECT (avoid SQL Injection)

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

is this the correct way to avoid SQL Injection in this SELECT?

```
// --[  Method  ]---------------------------------------------------------------
//
//  - Purpose   : Check if provided $email (taken from user input) exists in the DB
//
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
function DB_EmailExists($email)
{
    //
    if(DB_Connect() == false)
    {
        echo mysqli_error();
        return false;
    }

    //
    $stmt = $GLOBALS['global_db_link']->prepare("SELECT * FROM ".$GLOBALS['global_db_table_users']." WHERE Email=?");
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $email);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    $numrows = $stmt->num_rows;
    $stmt->close();

    //
    if ($numrows==0)
    {
        DB_Disconnect();
        return false;
    }

    //
    DB_Disconnect();

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Almost.  I would strongly suggest that you do NOT use $GLOBALS like that.  Inject the database into this class, and call it directly (`$this->db_link->prepare(....`)

Comment: 1) why downvoted?
2) why not use $GLOBALS like that, any explanation ?

Comment: Didn't downvote.  And there's plenty of resources on why $GLOBALS is not good: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557787/are-global-variables-in-php-considered-bad-practice-if-so-why and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12445972/stop-using-global-in-php and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8715897/why-is-it-considered-bad-practice-to-use-global-reference-inside-functions and https://tomnomnom.com/posts/why-global-state-is-the-devil-and-how-to-avoid-using-it and many others....

Comment: Thanks, will have a look into this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that works. But no need to `SELECT *`, just use `SELECT email`

Comment: Perfect, i have added re-captcha to ensure no 'bot' is submitting the POST too.

Comment: @Pees - captchas are not foolproof, and they are bad for user experience.  It's better to use other techniques to prevent bots.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/13158804/870729 as well as using a nonce: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4145531/how-to-create-and-use-nonces

Comment: @cale_b  Google's no-captcha is pretty legit though.